# C# versus XSLT for transforming XML data to html file

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

I am working on a project that generate HTML. The following are the steps.

1. Reads an XML file then update the XML file with some data
2. Generate the final XML
3. Transform this final XML using XSLT to HTML file - 
   The size of the XML is big and the transformed HTML file will have more than 10 printable pages(this is just to show you how big the single html file is). Beside the solution has to transform more than 4000's of different XML files. As the conditions of the HTML view for different products getting bigger, its becoming hard to satisfy using the XSLT Conditional statements and Templates. Its not that flexible to abstract whats common and differentiate across different HTML views. I was thinking to use C# to do the transformation instead of XSLT. But its gonna be a big task to implement all the XSLT job to a C# classes so I would like to know if its convincing to do it using C#. or if its a better option for my case.

Do you have any suggestions on this? Please let me know what you think: if i better clean the xslt and keep using it or I should use a new C# implementation.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the project grew in some unexpected ways and you may be well served by doing a re-write.  The next version of the project will be better cause you know more about the project, and how it's changing based on your experience.

Re-write it using the "best" technology, where "best" is defined by what your development team knows "best".  The solution can be equally clean in either C# or XSLT.

A 10 page HTML document isn't really very big, nor are 4,000 of them, XSLT would be fine.  Be sure that you're not calling too many templates (ie the template stack isn't too deep - more than 4 or 5 layers is deep), and that you're using <xsl:variable>s to eliminate multiple look-ups through the source XML to speed things up.

Comment: When you say deep, if you mean 1 calls 2 then 2 calls 3 then 3 calls 4 and so on? That may not be a lot but there may be cases(which I have to investigate). But I am sure lots of templates would be applied for a single XML file.

Comment: Template stack depth only really applies to calling templates procedurally, and calling templates procedurally is generally not the best way to organize XSLT code.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be one of the things I should look into. because right now, more than 30 templates will be applied to a single XML file(most of them are Template match so we dont call each specifically) but there are cases we apply templates by name or based on some value in the xml. In this case we apply templtes based on the order of the display on the html.

Comment: kjhughes makes a good point.

Comment: Be sure you're using variables (misspelled in my post) to eliminate multiple look-ups through the source.

Answer (score 3):

XSLT can be very clean and concise... But you'll need to keep it clean if you want it to perform well especially on the scope your speaking of. On the other hand i've imported large XML files into collections and it worked fairly efficiently. Its really personal preference. Considering that you are generating HTML as end result... Id probably stick with XSLT. 
Note: many developers are not as familiar with XSLT as other data transport languages... You may want to take that into consideration if others will be working with this often

Answer (score 2):

**XSLT is ideal for transforming XML to HTML or other XML**.  None of the concerns you raise are true obstacles; each has simple solutions that are well known by most XSLT developers:

- You don't mention specific performance requirements, but tens of
  printable pages and thousands of XML input files isn't excessive for
  XSLT projects.
- Proliferation of conditions is no problem for XSLT templates.  More
  specific templates take precedence, and the predicate language is so
  rich and well-tuned to XML that complex conditional processing is
  actually a strength, not a liability of well-written XSLT programs.
- Commonly used templates can be factored out of XSLT files and
  maintained separately in files that are easily imported or included
  where needed.
- More elaborate transformations can leverage multiple passes or staged
  application of templates (but I don't yet hear that any of your needs
  require such techniques).

**I strongly suggest that you stay the course with XSLT for your XML transformation project.**  *You may have the basis for a few separately asked Stack Overflow questions in your concerns, but nothing you've written is reason to switch to another language.*

Comment: Thanks, My fear is actually the complexity of the conditions inside the xslt is growing. Around 30 or more templates(most of them template match) will be applied for a single XML from different XSL file. And though time the size of the xslt also keep growing. This is because most part of the html display will have different presentation based on different needs. So it start frustrating me to manage all the conditions and templates.

Comment: To better deal with the complexity you describe, generally favor placement of conditionals in template patterns (eg `xsl:template/@match`) over statements within a template (eg `xsl:if/@test` and `xsl:when/@test`).  Strive for declarative, not procedural, organization of your code.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes. I will apply your suggestions. Thanks again